# Conditional list values replacement in Mathematica

Tags: replace, wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements

Please consider :

```
dalist = Transpose@{{"Noise1",1,1,1,1,1},{"Blah", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                   {"Noise2",2,2,2,2,2}, {"COGCondition", 1, 2, 1, 2, 1}}
```

[image]

```
COGCondition1 = 10
COGCondition2 = 20
```

I would like to replace the values in column "Blah" given the value taken in column "COGCondition" such that:

If, for a given row, the value in column "COGCondition" = 1 the value in column "Blah" should be equal to COGCondition1 (And 2 -> COGCondition2)

Desired output:

[image]

I need this for a large data set and my attempts using `Table` and `Switch` have failed. I can easily generate new columns but can't figure out how to replace values using `Switch`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use:

```
dalist[[2 ;;, 2]] =
 dalist[[2 ;;, 4]] /. {1 -> COGCondition1, 2 -> COGCondition2};

dalist //TableForm
```

[image]

If modification of `dalist` is undesired, you can copy it first, e.g. `dalist2 = dalist` and then modify the copy.

Especially if you have many values for the condition column, I suggest you follow the earlier recommendation to use an indexed variable (`COGCondition[1]`).  This would look like:

```
dalist[[2 ;;, 2]] = COGCondition /@ dalist[[2 ;;, 4]];
```

Comment: Or, if the conditions are expressed as a list of rules: `conditions = {1-> 10, 2-> 20}`, then `dalist[[2;;, 2]] = dalist[[2 ;;, 4]] /. conditions`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thank You very much. So Simple, it is impressive.

Comment: @500, thank you for choosing my solution, but I'd argue that this is the correct one. It is simpler to implement, and does not have some of the same problems as the pattern based one because of that. I'd use some of the ideas expressed in mine, like what to do with default values, but this one will get you up and running faster.

Answer (score 7):

This is fairly straightforward with a replacement rule:

```
dalist /.
  {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> 
  {Which[y==1, COGCondition1, y==2, COGCondition2], y}
```

gives

```
{{"Blah", "COGCondition"}, {10, 1}, {20, 2}, {10, 1}, {20, 2}, {10, 1}}.
```

Alternatively, you could use `MapThread`

```
MapThread[ 
    If[ !NumericQ[#2], #1,
      Which[#2==1, COGCondition1, #2==2, COGCondition2] ]&,
   Transpose@dalist]
```

which returns

```
{"Blah", 10, 20, 10, 20, 10}.
```

**Edit**: In your updated version of `dalist`, you have four columns: noise, data, noise, and condition.  The update to the pattern version is simply

```
dalist /.
  {a_, x_, b_, y_} :> 
  {a, Which[y==1, COGCondition1, y==2, COGCondition2], b, y}
```

Unfortunately, this is somewhat fragile because it requires a bit of extra work if you change the number of conditions. The method suggested by Leonid, was to create a function

```
Clear[COGCondition]
COGCondition[1] = 10
COGCondition[2] = 20
```

then this simplifies the update code

```
dalist /.
  {a_, x_, b_, y_Integer} :> {a, COGCondition[y], b, y}
```

Alternatively, you could create a list of rules

```
conditions = { 1 -> 10, 2 -> 20 }
```

then the code for changing `dalist` becomes

```
dalist /.
  {a_, x_, b_, y_Integer} :> {a, y /. conditions, b, y}
```

If you find that you have more than 1 column between `x` and `y`, then your pattern is simply `{a_, x_, b___, y_Integer}`.  Or, if the number of columns prior to `x` is larger than one, use `{a___, x_, b_, y_Integer}`.  However, they don't work together because Mathematica needs to know where `x` and `y` are relative to some point in the list, or it won't operate as you expect, if at all.

But, if you know the number of columns, you can use [`PatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternSequence.html).  For example, if you have 3 columns of noise, your data, 5 columns of noise, and then you condition, your replacement rule would be

```
dalist /.
  {a:PatternSequence@@Array[_&,3], x_, 
   b:PatternSequence@@Array[_&,5], y_Integer} :> {a, y /. conditions, b, y}
```

Now, `PatternSequence@@Array[_&,3]` could be written `PatternSequence[_, _, _]`, but by using `Array` it gives more flexibility.

---

**Edit**: One difficulty with either the indexed variable form, `COGCondition[n]`, or the rule form is if the condition column contains values other than 1 or 2.  The simplest solution is to set up a default value, e.g.

```
COGCondition[_] := default (*where default may be defined elsewhere *)
```

or add to `conditions`

```
_ :> default
```

One possibility is to emit a [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Message.html) whenever this default is encountered which would provide feed back as its running.

Another possibility is to have the data column remain untouched if the default is encountered. To accomplish this, we can use the following

```
COGCondition[1,_] := 10
(*define the rest of the known values as above*)
COGCondition[_,d_]:= default (*encountered only if the 1st var is unknown*)
```

which would be used like

```
dalist /.
  {a_, x_, b_, y_Integer} :> {a, COGCondition[y, x], b, y}.
```

To make this work with the rule implementation, we make `conditions` a function which accepts the current data value

```
conditions[dat_] := { 1 -> 10, 2 -> 20, _ :> dat }
```

which changes the code for updating `dalist` to

```
dalist /.
  {a_, x_, b_, y_Integer} :> {a, y /. conditions[x], b, y}.
```

Note, either of the last two methods can be combined with emitting a `Message` from above.

Comment: Thank You, but I must admit I can`t get any of the above to work :-( I don`t understand  {{"Blah", ...}, {"COGCondition", ...}}. And yet all return error :-(

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to use shorthand to make it more readable: `{"Blah", ...} = {"Blah", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, and similarly for `{"COGCondition", ...}`.

Comment: @Leonid, I didn't even see that bug. Thanks.

Comment: @500, I fixed the bug and added several ways to make the code more flexible.

Comment: @rcollyer Ok, deleted mine. +1 for PatternSequence.

Comment: `dalist /. {a_, x_, b_, y_Integer} :> {a, COGCondition[y], b, y}` only works if the y column only contains 1's and 2's. This is suggested by the OP's examples, but never stated explicitly. The same problem occurs in `dalist /. {a_, x_, b_, y_Integer} :> {a, y /. conditions, b, y}`. @Mr.Wizard's implementation is better in this respect.

Comment: @Sjoerd, @Mr.Wizard's implementation runs into the same problem, it is also dependent on the values for which `COGCondition` is defined. If the `y` column contained a 3, for instance, it would return `COGCondition[3]` at that value. However, the rule formulation would return 3, as there is no match for it. This could be resolved by either defining `COGCondition[_]:=default` or adding `_ :> default` to the list of rules.

Comment: @Sjoerd, I updated my solution with the ability to use a default value or retain the original value in the data. I also suggested using `Message` when these values are encountered.

Comment: @rcollyer,Leonid & Sjoerd, It is and I believe will always remain amazing for me to see experts answers and explanations on this forum, Thank you.

Comment: @500, thank you for including me in that list. I always feel humbled, though, by Leonid and Sjoerd, and many of the others.

Comment: @rcollyer you're right about Mr.wiz's solution. And the humbled feeling is reciprocal...