# Matching a Finite Range of Elements with Patterns

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

While working on my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079244/conditional-list-values-replacement-in-mathematica/7079357#7079357), it occurred to me that it is difficult to match a finite range of elements.  With the built in patterns, you can match 1 element (`_`), 1 or more elements (`__`), or zero or more elements (`___`).  To match more than one element, I used [`PatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternSequence.html), like this

```
a:PatternSequence[_,_,_]
```

or, more generically

```
a:PatternSequence@@Array[_&,3].
```

(Using a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) would have also worked.) To match a range of n to m elements we could do

```
a:Alternatives@@( PatternSequence @@@ Array[_&, {n,m}] ),
```

but that is a rather convoluted way to accomplish something that can be done by

```
a__ /; n <= Length[{a}] <= m.
```

However, this brings up an interesting question, using the [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) form it is straightforward to match the range 0 to n,

```
a___ /; Length[{a}] <= n,
```

but can this be done using patterns alone, i.e. without using `Condition` (`/;`)?  More specifically, how would one go about matching 0 elements without adding a condition?  Also, which is faster?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe you could do something with `Repeated`. E.g.

```
Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1,2}}, {Repeated[_, {2, 4}]}]
```

gives the same result as

```
Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1,2}}, {a___ /; 2 <= Length[{a}] <= 4}]
```

The first method seems faster than the second. For example

```
tab = Table[Range[RandomInteger[1000]], {1000}];
Timing[t1 = Cases[tab, {a___ /; 0 <= Length[{a}] <= 100}];]
Timing[t2 = Cases[tab, {Repeated[_, {0, 100}]}];]
SameQ[t1, t2]
```

returns on my system

```
{0.027801, Null}

{0.000733, Null}

True
```

Comment: +1, I never thought to look at the `FullForm` of `Repeated`.  It performs exactly like I expected.  I will wait to see if there are any other answers.

Comment: +1 Me too. Updates to old&basic functions are often very useful, but may get by unnoticed for years. I remember the addition of the {i,{2,8,34,3.5,6}} type of index specification in `Table` and `Do`. It must have been there for years before I stumbled upon this very useful feature. But who's going to lookup `Table` if you have been using it for ages?

Comment: +1 I use `Repeated` enough that I have a custom notation for it.  I enter this pattern:  `Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2}}, {_ .. {2, 4}}]` (the space after `_` is required).  Frankly, I don't know why there is not something like this by default.

Comment: @rcollyer what I mean is, I used the Notations package/palette to create a notation, such that the line in my comment in equivalent to the top code line in the post above.  I have been using it for several years, and while I cannot rule out incompatibilities with other coding styles, I have yet to run into a problem with it, that I know of.